# source for camera video recorder without using intent

Tags: android, activerecord, video, camera

Does someone know where I could find sample source code that records video and saves it on the device? The code should not use `intent`.

I tried using this code:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691152/android-recording-a-video-initializing-the-camera-2
 that I saw in YouTube tutorial, but I can't get it to work.

I can't use `intent` because, I need to resize the videoview when the camera is recording.

I think I can't do this using `intent`, or am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source that is using `intent` can be found in: 
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html

A good video explanation (but the code doesn't work):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZScE1aXS1Rs

Eventually i read this :

Here's [a link] (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)!

and use it to create camera app, the best way ...

important advice : when you pause the cam use :

```
if (isRecording) {
            // stop recording and release camera
            mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
            mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

            // inform the user that recording has stopped
            //setCaptureButtonText("Capture");

            isRecording = false;

        }

        PauseAndRelease();  //add this before finish to use in the camera


public void PauseAndRelease ()
{
     releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
     releaseCamera();  // release the camera immediately on pause event
     Log.d(TAG,"camera on pause" + mCamera );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `SurfaceView` and utilizing the `MediaRecorder`. You can resize the video that way, manage where the video should be saved, etc.

An example can be found here: http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2011/04/simple-exercise-of-video-capture-using.html